# How to use conditional statement IF ELSE on property attribute

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, attributes, conditional-operator

I want to show `MyProperty1` or `MyProperty2` based on **MyPropertySelected**. How to use a conditional statement `if` or `else` based on **MyPropertySelected**? Thanks.

```
// [Browsable(true)
// ????? conditional statement IF ELSE in here..
// IF (MyPropertySelected) MyProperty1 will be show ELSE MyProperty2 will be show.
public bool MyPropertySelected { get; set; }

// [Browsable(true) or [Browsable(false) depending on MyPropertySelected condition.
public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }

// [Browsable(true) or [Browsable(false) depending on MyPropertySelected condition.
public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
```

Comment: It's not clear, how you want to use attributes...

Comment: I want binding above properties to property grid with conditional as follows: MyPropertySelected always Browsable(true). If i selected MyPropertySelected value to true on property grid, MyProperty1 will be set to Browsable(true) and MyProperty2 to MyProperty2 to Browsable(false).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing apples with oranges.

*Attributes* are metadata and a property value acquires *its value* on run-time.

In other words: *attribute* is something that you'll access using **[reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** and those aren't tied to a particular object but to the type of the object (i.e. *the class*).

Another issue is that you want to add an attribute to a property based on a condition that can't work in compile-time.

Your `MyPropertySelected` won't get any value until its enclosing class gets instantiated *- that's creating an object, for example: `MyClass a = new MyClass()`-*, **meaning that adding or not adding the attribute would never be a compile-time choice**.

I want to be clear: **you can't do what you want purely using attributes!**

*You can't conditionally apply attributes based on run-time values*.

Finally, I suspect you want to make something `Browsable` based on a condition, like  your own question says. You can't do that.

### Ok ok, but what...?

You can workaround your situation with a different software design.

#### 1)

First, create an interface that will have any of the properties that would be browsable or not. But don't apply the attribute `[Browsable(bool)]` to the interface properties.

#### 2)

Create two classes that implements the previously created interface.

In the first class, implement the interface properties and put a `[Browsable(true)]` attribute on them. In the second class, do the same, but this time put a `[Browsable(false)]` on them.

#### 3)

Some code that creates the instance of the object will be the one that will also decide *which one will be instantiated*.

That is, externalizing `MyPropertySelected` outside of both classes and performing the whole condition switch in the caller.

```
public interface IBrowsableProperties
{
   int Property1 { get;set; }
   int Property2 { get;set; }
}

public class A : IBrowsableProperties
{ 
   [Browsable(true)]
   public int Property1 { get;set; }

   [Browsable(true)]
   public int Property1 { get;set; }
}

public class B : IBrowsableProperties
{
   [Browsable(false)]
   public int Property1 { get;set; }

   [Browsable(false)]
   public int Property1 { get;set; }
}

// Somewhere in some method...
bool propertySelected = true;

IBrowsableProperties instance = null;

if(propertySelected) 
{
   instance = new A();
}
else
{
   instance = new B();
}

// ... do stuff with your instance of IBrowsableProperties!
```

## UPDATE

*I've reviewed some of your question's comments and I've found you're working with `PropertyGrid` control.*

*Anyway, you can apply the concept in your case. `PropertyGrid` can be inherited. You can create both `PropertyGrid1` and `PropertyGrid2` derived classes that both implement the proposed interface!*

Comment: @YD4 No problem! You're welcome. Check my update on the bottom of my answer, it should be a good hint for you :)

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov Thank you! I got inspired :D

Answer (score 3):

You probably want an intermediary property like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public bool MyPropertySelected
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public readonly int MyProperty
    {
        get 
        {
            return MyPropertySelected ? MyProperty1 : MyProperty2;
        }
    }

    private int MyProperty1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private int MyProperty2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```